# How to prove that a subset is open in another one?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $B$ be a Banach space. Let $U\subset B$ be an open subset and $K\subset B$ be a compact subset.
Define
$$\mathscr{L}=\{f:K\to B: f\mbox{ is continuous}\}$$
which is complete metric space endowed with the dustance
$$d_{\mathscr{L}} =\max_{x\in K} |f_1(x)-f_2(x)|_{\infty}, \quad f_1,f_2\in \mathscr{L}.$$

I need to prove that
$$\mathscr{L}_U=\{f\in \mathscr{L}: f(x)\in U\}$$
is open in $\mathscr{L}$.

I was thinking about proving that it is the union of some collection of open balls, but I am not able to prove that.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is $U$ used? Is there perhaps a typo. Furthermore your title is way too vague

Comment: also, you should be clearer on “$f(x)\in A$”: I assume you mean $f(K)\subseteq A$ but $x$ could be inferred as a specific point

Comment: You have said what $B$, $U$, $K$ and $\mathscr{L}$ are, but what is $A$? And what is $x$?

Comment: Also what is the topology on $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: I am in complete agreement with Lee’s comment. Furthermore you should specify a topology on $L$: since each function is continuous on a compact space it will attain its maximum norm so I assume you want the maximum norm metric topology, but we shouldn’t have to guess...

Comment: I apologize to everyone, there were some typos and missing information. The question has been edited.

Comment: @FShrike question edited.

Comment: @C.Bishop Does my interpretation answer your question?

Comment: @FShrike the question has been edited. I do not understand the point $2.$ of your "interpretation". Could you please clarify? And what "$r-$ why?" means. Thank you.

Comment: @C.Bishop I wrote my answer before your edit, but point $2)$ was in fact the same as the distance you endowed the space with in your edited post: its name is called the “maximum norm topology”. I also said $r=r’$ works, and the “- why?” Was just some punctuation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\l}{\mathscr{L}}$I will be assuming that $x$ is a prescribed and fixed point in $U$.

The (more wordy than usual, to hopefully address all concerns) proof of the result:

> Take an $f\in\l_U$ arbitrarily: by definition, $f(x)\in U$ and $U$ is open, which in the metric topology (because you specified a Banach space i.e. a normed space) implies that there is an $r\gt0$ such that the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $f(x)$ is contained in $U$ - in symbols: $$\tag{$\ast$}\{y\in B:\|y-f(x)\|\lt r\}\subseteq U$$That is, if some $y\in B$ satisfies $\|y-f(x)\|\lt r$ we can be certain that $y\in U$.
>
> Claim: the open ball of the same radius $r$, centred at $f$, is contained in $\l_U$: $$\mathcal{B}(f,r)=\{g\in\l:\|g-f\|_{\max}\lt r\}\subseteq\l_U$$
>
> This is because, for any $g\in \mathcal{B}(f,r)$, $\|g-f\|_{\max}\lt r\implies\|g(x)-f(x)\|\lt r$ (otherwise, $x$ would be a point of contradiction to the maximum being $r$, $\|g-f\|_{\max}\lt r$ would be false). However, we know that $g(x)\in B$ and that $\|g(x)-f(x)\|\lt r$, so by $(\ast)$ we have $g(x)\in U$. By definition of $\l_U$, the fact that $g\in\l$ and $g(x)\in U$ means that $g\in\l_U$. As $g\in A$ was arbitrary, we know that *all* $g\in\mathcal{B}(f,r)$ satisfy $g\in\l_U$, that is $\mathcal{B}(f,r)\subseteq\l_U$ as desired.
>
> Since we now know that about *any* $f\in\l_U$ satisfies that there is an open ball $\mathcal{B}(f,r)\subseteq\l_U$, we know by definition of the metric topology on $\l$ that $\l_U\subseteq\l$ is an open set.

Now for the background topological prerequisites:

> A topology is a collection of sets satisfying some simple axioms, the one which we'll use here being the axiom that the arbitrary union of open sets is again open (all that "open" means is that the set is a member of the topology - the topology is a collection of sets).
>
> It is a general fact that, in any topological space, if a set $U$ is open if and only if every $x\in U$ has an open set $N_x$ with $x\in N_x\subseteq U$ ($N_x$ is called a *neighbourhood* of $x$).
>
> The proof:
>
> Suppose $U$ is open. Then every $x\in U$ has a neighbourhood $N_x$ contained in $U$ by specifying $N_x=U$, trivially. Conversely, if all $x\in U$ have a neighbourhood $N_x\subseteq U$, then $\bigcup_{x\in U}N_x\subseteq U$ as each $N_x\subseteq U$, but also because every $x\in U$ has $x\in N_x$ by definition, we have $\bigcup_{x\in U}N_x\supseteq U$. Therefore $\bigcup_{x\in U}N_x=U$. As the **arbitrary union of open sets is open** and each $N_x$ is open, $U$ must also be open.
>
> In a metric space, the topology is *generated* by the open balls (the sets of the form $(\ast)$, which contain all points within some distance $r$ of the centre) which means that every (nonempty) open set contains an open ball. In particular, by the above theorem, about each $x$ in an open set $U$, we can find an $r\gt0$ so that the ball of radius $r$, about $x$, is contained in $U$. Conversely, if I can find about every $x\in U$ an open ball contained in $U$, then by the above theorem $U$ is the union of open neighbourhoods of its points, hence open.
>
> So I used this to find the $r\gt0$ so that $(\ast)$ holds true. I then used the converse of this at the end: as for every $f\in\l_U$ there was an open ball $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\l_U$, I concluded that $\l_U$ was open. By "open *in* $\l$" we mean $\l_U\subseteq\l$ and that $\l_U$ is an open set of the topology on $\l$ (since $\l$ is a metric space that more directly means that every element of $\l_U$ is contained in a ball under the metric on $\l$) - which was the maximum norm topology (the $\max_{x\in K}$ thing). If I gave $\l$ a different topology, $\l_U$ might not be open anymore, since openness is an abstract concept dependent on the topology.
>
> Final point: the maximum norm is a little subtle. The maximum **might not exist in general**, but since $K$ is *compact* and each $f$ is *continuous*, the image $f(K)$ **is again compact**. In any metric space, compact implies closedness and boundedness: $f(K)$ bounded implies there is a finite upper bound to the value of $\|f(x)\|$ over $x\in K$, and closedness implies that there is actually a point in $K$ for which $f(x)$ *attains* this maximum. Then the maximum norm does make sense as the maximum actually exists!

Comment: FShrike, thank you for the question, but it seems still not so clear for me (starting from what means that a subset A of a set B is open in B). Could you please edit/make some more comments? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @C.Bishop Sure, when I get the chance. What background should I target the explanation for? Judging by the question you surely know what the definition of a topology is, of what a compact set/space is, of what a continuous function is... perhaps you could say what exactly has you confused (eg what’s wrong with saying that $A$ is an open subset? The meaning of this is just the definition of topology - $A$ is in the collection of “open” sets)

Comment: FShrike if $\mathscr{L}$ is a metric space, what means that $\mathscr{L}_U$ is open in $\mathscr{L}$ and clarify a bit the steps of your proof. Nothing more.

Comment: @C.Bishop I have given a thorough edit! I hope it addresses your concerns.  See [this](https://s2pnd-matematika.fkip.unpatti.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Real-Analysis-4th-Ed-Royden.pdf) textbook for a thorough introduction to metric spaces and topology (among other things)